# I can't change the position of a UIView

Tags: interface-builder, position

I can't change the positions of a UIView as you can see in the following screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvcw.png

The positions of the UIView are static - x:-20, y:16

How can I change the values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want do this from IB then delete it and make again or do it prog.

Programmaticaly you can do like  this

```
 CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.x=0;
    viewFrame.origin.y=0;

//also you set height and width
    viewFrame.size.height=460;
    viewFrame.size.width=320;
    self.view.frame=viewFrame;
```

Comment: I deleted it and made it again, so it initiated 0, 0.
But if I set the View's autosizing, it change its positions automatically like -16, 11. So I can't set the View's autosizing.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why not go with programatically.

Comment: I thoght that it has some problems so it changes the positions. So I wanted to solve it in interface builder.. Ok I'll try it programmatically. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: ok if your prob is solved then you need to accept the ans by checking the checkmark before the ans.

Comment: you can see a check mark on right side of the ans you need to click on that it creates a green check mark.

Comment: No rep matters for acceptence, acc make your rep.see the right hand side of the que you see a hollow check mark you need to click on that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out playing with the size values and the layout position.

Click on the lowest-right dot in the dotted square. You will notice that both position values change. Now enter in the width field the new 'x' value and in the height field the new 'y' value. Click now on the upper-left dot and both 'x' and 'y' will reset to zero. You can now enter a new size and the view will be centered to its size.

Comment: Or you may open the xib file in plain text mode, and find those values